# .net Datagrid WinForm - Adding a DataGridViewButtonColumn Automatically Adds a Row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

When adding a new DataGridViewButtonColumn to a DataGrid, a new row of buttons is added.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I'd prefer not to have to clear all the rows after adding columns.

Also, can't use WPF. This is a Winform project I inherited.

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn bcol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
 bcol.HeaderText = "Button Column";
 bcol.Text = "Click Me";
 bcol.Name = "btnClickMe";
```

The above code snippet creates a new row with a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disallowing adding new rows:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

I think what you're seeing is the new row at the bottom of your grid.

You can see the difference here: *(enabled in the top pic, disabled in the bottom pic)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also found if you uncheck "Enable Adding" in the designer will work too. These must be the same properties.